# Easier way to update files on Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Major newbie when it comes to Amazon EC2 servers, and web development in general.

At the moment I have a web app that is hosted on parse. Everything is done on the client side in the browser, and I want to change it to a client server model by writing a server in node.js.

I've looked into Amazon EC2, I've set up and instance and it looks good. My question is however:

Is there an easier way to update files on the instance? At the moment I'm pushing all the files from my computer to a github repo, then pulling them on to the instance- this seems very long winded. When using parse, all I needed to type was 'parse deploy' into the command line to update and deploy my application, is there something like this for Amazon EC2?

Thank you

Comment: Is it windows instance or linux instance?

Comment: @sailesh Linux instance

Comment: Ok, Which personal computer are you using? Windows or Mac or other?

Comment: it may seem "long winded", but *using version control is a good thing*. Having said that, rsync is a fast and elegant option.

Answer (score 0):

I typically install or enable FTP on my ec2 instances and then just use the ftp client of my choice to update files.